# What is the difference between gauge transformation and canonical transformation？

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Recently I have been studying theoretical mechanics, then I have this question, Is the gauge transformation the same as the canonical transformation？

Comment: Gauge transformation is for Lagrangian. If new Lagrangian is being constructed from the original one through the gauge transformation ($L'(q,\dot q,t)=L(q,\dot q,t)+\frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}$), then the Lagrange's equation remains invariant. While canonical transformations are the subset of contact transformations (transformations on phase space) such that the Hamilton's equations remain invariant (though with the new Hamiltonian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between the two.

Canonical transformations are transformations that preserve the form of the Hamilton's equations so that

$$ q,p \to Q,P \Rightarrow \quad\{Q, P\}_{q,p} = 1 $$

where $q,p$ are the original canonical coordinates and $Q,P$ the new ones.

Gauge transformations are those that preserve the Lagrangian  such that

$$L\rightarrow L' = L + \frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}$$